# Mapping features based on their priority counts in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a table like so:

```
Feature priority n
happy   low      2
happy   high     5
sad     low      7
sad     high     10
goofy   high     2
mad     low      4
mad     high     3
worry   high     5
worry   low      5
```

I want to label these features by which ever priority occurs more often.

For example happy would be labeled high because it occurs 5 times compared to low 2 times.
If a feature has both a high and low priority and they are both equal then the priority should be medium.

Expected output:

```
Feature priority
happy   high
sad     high
goofy   high
mad     low
worry   medium
```

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'Feature', `filter` the rows where the 'n' is `max`, then `summarise` the 'priority' by replacing the value to 'medium' `if` there are more than one row (`n() > 1`) and (`&`) if `all` the 'high', 'low' are present, then return 'medium' or `else` return priority

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Feature) %>%
   filter(n == max(n)) %>% 
   summarise(priority = if(n() >1 & 
           all(c("high", "low") %in% priority)) "medium" else priority)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Feature priority
#  <chr>   <chr>   
#1 goofy   high    
#2 happy   high    
#3 mad     low     
#4 sad     high    
#5 worry   medium
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Feature = c("happy", "happy", "sad", "sad", "goofy", 
"mad", "mad", "worry", "worry"), priority = c("low", "high", 
"low", "high", "high", "low", "high", "high", "low"), n = c(2L, 
5L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: This is really awesome! Thanks. I forgot to mention one thing. If there's a tie, I would like to label it as medium. Do you know how I could implement that?

Comment: @Eisen if your max value for a particular feature have only 'low' prioririty, how would that change

Comment: If theres only a low priority for a particular feature it would be low and vice versa.

Comment: @Eisen Suppose your first two values i.e. for happy are 'priority' 'high' and both have 'n' as 5.  In that case, you want it as `medium`?

Comment: @Eisen Perhaps `df1 %>% group_by(Feature) %>% filter(n == max(n)) %>% mutate(priority = if(n() > 1 & all(priority == 'high')) 'medium' else priority) %>% distinct(Feature, .keep_all = TRUE)` (Not clear about the tie condition exactly)

Comment: So a feature can only have at most two priorities: high and low. If low and high are both the same value (say 5).  I would want the feature to have a medium priority.

Comment: @Eisen can you please update with a new example.  My condition was checking if there are multiple rows based on the tie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218485/discussion-between-eisen-and-akrun).